# iPhone : Implement Ole Leaves API

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, sdk

Hi I am recently work with [Leaves](https://github.com/ole/leaves) api and I  have problem with this , I need to display a PDF file , and my `ViewController` class has a nib file , I  implement the code base on API sample code but does not show anything ! Am I missing something ?

```
#import "BookViewController.h"
#import "Utilities.h"

@implementation BookViewController



/////EDITED//////////////


- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"BookViewController" bundle:nil]) {

        CFURLRef pdfURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), CFSTR("paper.pdf"), NULL, NULL);
        pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
        CFRelease(pdfURL);

    }
    return self;
}





- (void)dealloc {
    CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf);
    [super dealloc];
}



- (void) displayPageNumber:(NSUInteger)pageNumber {
    self.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                 @"Page %u of %u", 
                                 pageNumber, 
                                 CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf)];
}



#pragma mark  LeavesViewDelegate methods

- (void) leavesView:(LeavesView *)leavesView willTurnToPageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)pageIndex {
    [self displayPageNumber:pageIndex + 1];
}



#pragma mark LeavesViewDataSource methods

- (NSUInteger) numberOfPagesInLeavesView:(LeavesView*)leavesView {
    return CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf);
}

- (void) renderPageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, index + 1);
    CGAffineTransform transform = aspectFit(CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox),
                                            CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(ctx));
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, page);
}


#pragma mark UIViewController

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    leavesView.backgroundRendering = YES;
    [self displayPageNumber:1];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you instantiating your controller?

If you call `initWithNibName` (as I suppose you do, since you say it has a nib file), you are totally skipping your local `init` method (i.e., the one in BookController); therefore, the PDF handling is not initialized at all.

Try renaming your init method to `initWithNibName`, and it should work; or create an `initWithNibName` and make it call you `init` (google for "designated constructor" to learn more about this pattern).

Notice that the full signature of `initWithNibName` is:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle
```

You have more options available, like creating the controller by calling `init` (instead of `initWithNibName`) or even create a method `setPDF`, then, after you create the controller any way you like, you can call this method, which in turns calls `initialize`, etc...

EDIT: if you decide to instantiate manually the controller, don't forget to define `loadView`:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    if (leavesView) {
        leavesView.frame = self.view.bounds;
        leavesView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [self.view addSubview:leavesView];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I change it to the initWithNibName , but does not change anything would you please see my edited question and check it again

Comment: Is there any way to load pdf without nib file ? because my app is Universal

Comment: well, then you need a `init` method (not `initWithNibName`), then you explicitly instantiate it when you need it (from you app delegate?) and add its view to where it belongs (if in you app delegate to the main window). you also need implementing `loadView` in your controller (see my edit in a couple of seconds)